# Generic reducer to remove items with specific properties that have nullish values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create a generic reducer in TypeScript wherein for an array `T[]`

- I specify a property name `K in keyof T`
- The array is reduced to `{ [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P] }[]`

The following reducer does not properly narrow the type

```
export const reduceRemoveIfPropertyEmpty =
  <T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(prop: K) =>
  (
    agg: { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P] }[],
    item: T
  ) => {
    item[prop] && agg.push({ ...item, [prop]: item[prop] })
    return agg
  }
```

I encounter the following error on `agg.push(...)`

| TS Error |
| --- |
| Argument of type 'T & { [x: string]: T[K]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P]; }'.ts(2345) |
| (parameter) prop: K extends keyof T |

**Notes**

**`tsconfig`** has `"strict"` and `"strictNullChecks"` enabled

Comment: ① Naming convention note: in `[k in keyof T]`, `k` is a *type parameter* (not a key name) and conventionally should be written as such.  So you might want `[K in keyof T]` oops I guess you're already using `K`, so maybe `[P in keyof T]`.  (Mapped types are not index signatures like `[k: string]`, where `k` is the form of a computed key name and thus a variable)

Comment: ② I think if you're happy with the implementation you'll probably just want to use a type assertion in there; the compiler will never be able to accurately type check a generic conditional type like `agg` inside the body of the function.  You might be able to rewrite the code to avoid an error, but it won't be because the function is really checked as type safe.  So assert away if you want. I'll write up some suggested code when I get a chance and have you look at it, if nobody makes a better suggestion before I get off mobile.

Comment: Made the case-change for property. I've posted a suggested solution below but I am unhappy because I use a run-time type-guard 

Comment: Can you check [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ08vW)? As @jcalz said, it won't be possible to do perfectly, however, this approach will require you to pass at least `{..item}`, but `[prop]: item[prop]` won't be important for it

Comment: Interesting, ts-playground doesn't show any problem but `tsc --noEmit` encounteres this error (I use typescript 4.9.3) `error TS2345: Argument of type 'T & { [x: string]: T[K]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; } & { [P in K & keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>; }'.
  Type 'T & { [x: string]: T[K]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in K & keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>; }'.`

Comment: I assume you have `strictNullChecks` option enabled in your `tsconfig`, which can be the reason of the error

Comment: yes, `"strict": true` 

Comment: you may try doing this: `item && item[prop] && agg.push({ ...item, [prop]: item[prop]! });`

Comment: I would rather avoid forced assertions, if I was to go that way.. I might as well use `as` assertion.

Comment: Oops, I forgot `NonNullable` ignore, please

Answer (score 1):

Object types do not get re-evaluated after property checks (...yet [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384)). You could use a type-guard as an alternative which uses run-time checks.

```
type TypeWithValueForProp<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P]
}

const isTypeWithValueForProp = <T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
  item: T,
  property: K
): item is TypeWithValueForProp<T, K> => {
  const value = item[property]
  return typeof value !== 'undefined' && typeof value !== null
}

const reduceRemoveIfPropertyEmpty =
  <T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(prop: K) =>
  (agg: TypeWithValueForProp<T, K>[], item: T) => {
    isTypeWithValueForProp(item, prop) && agg.push(item)
    return agg
  }
```

Comment: I'm definitely not seeing anything "morally" superior to the type guard function you wrote; if you're going to use the operation of "checking a single prop for non-nullability" often then a type guard is useful. And you need a runtime operation no matter what to check for nullishness; it's just refactored to a function here, but you have to do it no matter what. But if you're only doing this check inside the reducer then you might as well use a single type assertion [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WP8REW).  What do you want to do here? I *could* write an answer but it doesn't seem needed.

Comment: My tiff with “as” assertion is that, it creates an escape hatch that removes the implicit mathematical correctness achieved through typescript types. You are correct in stating there is nothing “morally” better using the type guard because it is a glorified “as” assertion and gives room to errors. I am looking for a solution that uses natural type narrowing to translate the source type to the result type

Comment: There isn't such a solution; object types don't narrow based on property checks.  There is an open feature request at [ms/TS#42384](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) for that.  Until and unless that happens you either assert (if you're doing it once) or write a custom type guard (if you want to do it more than once and confine the type safety hole to the implementation of that one function). ...

Comment: (continued) ... I'm happy to write up an answer but maybe you just want to [edit] this and mention that there's nothing better yet as per ms/TS#42384? And [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) prevents the spread workaround you tried in your question (which would be a weird solution anyway).

Comment: Updated the answer with reference to property check translation problem. I am confused why the speard is a bad solution? the `prop` type is known as `K` and `T[K]` is known to be truthy because of the check before. Why would this be a bad solution except the fact that TS doesn't properly preserve it?

Comment: I said it was weird, not bad. Conceptually you just need to push the existing object onto the array, not copy pieces of it into a new object multiple times.  If the spread version appeased TS then it would at least be a motivation to do it, but it’s still weird.

Comment: Hmmm I have a feeling I am about to learn something groundbreaking here ^^, Say I have a type `type Alpha = {name: string; age?: number}[]` and I wish to filter this and pass as props (pardon the react talk) to a component that expects a type `type Beta = {name: string, age: number}[]`. How would you recommend achieving this without `as` assertion?